# Good breaststroke times according to age and gender

Tags: swimming

[runninglevel.com](https://runninglevel.com/) is a really useful site for gauging your progress at running as it gives target times for different levels of ability for a range of distances, according to age and gender.  There is also [swimminglevel.com](https://swimminglevel.com/swimming-times/1500-yd-times), which does the same thing, but for swimming.  However, it doesn't give different tables for different strokes as far as I can see, which would make a substantial difference.  Does anyone know of something similar but specific to breaststroke†?

† 54 year old hoping to get back to swimming 1500m in less than 30 minutes, wondering how slow today's 32:01 (2/3 breaststroke, 1/3 freestyle) really was ("intermediate", better than 59% of swimmers according to swimminlevel.com, but that may be assuming I was swimming freestyle).

Comment: 1000 Breastroke isn’t an event, so you aren’t going to find reference times for it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike that is a pity.  I am not a competitive swimmer, just looking for a gauge of swimming speed that would apply to me.  Unfortunately I am more a distance swimmer than a sprinter, 200m is hardly worth the bother ;o)

Comment: @DikranMarsupial - This isn't really a great fit for the site, but what you can do is look at reference times for 200m free and 200m breaststroke, calculate the % difference then apply that difference calculation to 1500 free. So if 200m Free is 2:00 and 200m Br is 2:30 you have a difference of + 25%.

Comment: @JohnP may give that a try.  Probably easier to improve my freestyle instead ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah like the comments say I’m not sure what you’re looking for exists for swimming. For the common competitive distances/strokes, there’s times standards for youth teams, but that’s all I know of.

If what you’re looking for does exist, they might be provided by “Masters Swimming”. It’s the competitive governing body for adult swim teams. Beyond that, you might just have to join a Masters group in your area for a swim or two and see how you stack up.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately team and competitive swimming is unlikely to be my thing.